# Nginx - why isn't uwsgi_cache working with this headers?

Tags: caching, nginx, web2py, uwsgi

I'm using Nginx + uWsgi + web2py framework, and I want to make Nginx to cache the HTML responses generated by web2py.

The HTML headers generated by web2py are these:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=300, s-maxage=300, public
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:147
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 27 Mar 2017 16:27:54 GMT
Expires:lun, 27 mar 2017 16:32:54 GMT
Server:Rocket 1.2.6 Python/2.7.6
X-Powered-By:web2py
```

Those are the ones served directly with the web2py embedded server.
The same request served with nginx and uwsgi (without any cache configuration) produces these headers:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=300, s-maxage=300, public
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 27 Mar 2017 16:31:09 GMT
Expires:lun, 27 mar 2017 16:36:09 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:web2py
```

Now, I want to implement `uwsgi_cache` for nginx configuration, and I'm trying like this:

```
uwsgi_cache_path /tmp/nginx_cache/ levels=1:2 keys_zone=mycache:10m max_size=10g inactive=10m use_temp_path=off;

server {  
    listen 80;
    server_name  myapp.com;
    root /home/user/myapp;

    location / {
        uwsgi_cache mycache;
        uwsgi_cache_valid 200 15m;
        uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;

        add_header X-uWSGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        expires 1h;

        uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/myapp.socket;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
    }
}
```

However, every time I hit an URL, I get a MISS in the response headers, indicating that nginx didn't serve the request from cache:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=3600
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 27 Mar 2017 16:37:29 GMT
Expires:Mon, 27 Mar 2017 22:37:29 GMT
Server:nginx
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:web2py
X-uWSGI-Cache:MISS
```

The nginx process is running as "www-data" user/group. I've checked the permissions of the folder /tmp/nginx_cache/ and they are ok: the user has permissions to read and write the folder. Also, inside the /tmp/nginx_cache/ a "temp" folder is created by nginx, but no cache files are written there.

I've tried also adding `proxy_ignore_headers` to location block in order to instruct nginx to ignore some headers like Set-Cookie and Cache-Control, like this:

```
location / {
        uwsgi_cache mycache;
        uwsgi_cache_valid 200 15m;
        uwsgi_cache_key $scheme$proxy_host$uri$is_args$args;

        add_header X-uWSGI-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie Vary;

        uwsgi_pass      unix:///tmp/myapp.socket;
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_param     UWSGI_SCHEME $scheme;
        uwsgi_param     SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
}
```

However, this makes no difference: the first request isn't cached, and all the subsequent requests are a MISS, that is, they aren't served from cache.

I've found this similar post, where the person who answers points out that it could be a problem of the response headers generated by (in this case) web2py:
https://serverfault.com/questions/690164/why-is-this-nginx-setup-not-caching-responses

Why nginx isn't caching the responses?

Comment: Your uwsgi_cache_key uses proxy_host which might not be defined in this context. Can you comment out that line and retest?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've changed uwsgi_cache_key to this:
`uwsgi_cache_key $request_uri;`
...but the behaviour is the same, nginx doesn't cache uwsgi responses :/

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I also tried removing the `uwsgi_cache_key` directive, but it didn't make any difference. When removing that directive, nginx warns me at start saying `no "uwsgi_cache_key" for "uwsgi_cache"`. However, the behaviour is still the same: nginx doesn't cache uwsgi responses.

Comment: Can you try the updated cache key and remove the proxy_ignore_headers? NGINX won't cache content with no expiration date.

Comment: I've tried that same configuration without the `proxy_ignore_headers` directive, but still the same. Also tried only ignoring the Set-Cookie header, although it's not necessary because the Set-Cookie header is not present in the response generated by my app.
I'm pretty lost with this :/

Comment: I think it has something to do with uwsgi_cache_key. Can you try configuring it like in the example here http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html#uwsgi_cache_key

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @FaisalMemon, but I had no luck with that. Tried to set `uwsgi_cache_key localhost:9000$request_uri;` but the result was the same: always a MISS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause of the issue: I was mixing uwsgi_cache_* directives with proxy_cache_* directives, and they belong to different Nginx modules. I just **needed to replace proxy_ignore_headers with uwsgi_ignore_headers**.

Notice that [proxy_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) module is different than [uwsgi_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_uwsgi_module.html), they have very similar directives, but they are two different modules.